# Bootstrap Modal not work correctly

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have a jsa page Test.jsp page .There are two modal in the page.data is dynamically loded in modal. second modal open at first modal link.when both modal are open when i close second modal first modal also close and also scroll is not work correctly.

**FIRST MODAL**

```
<div id="panelModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Department Details</h4>
                </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Panel Name</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="panel1" text=""></label></td>
                                                 <td class="col-md-2">Panel Price</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="price1" text=""></label></td>    
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Description</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="description1"></label></td>  
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Mapped Test </td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2" id="tests">
                                                    </td> 
                                            </tr>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**SECOND MODAL**

```
<div id="testModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Test Details</h4>
                </div>
    <!--            <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body"> -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Test Common Name</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="testName1" text=""></label></td>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Test Technical Name</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="technicalName"></label></td>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Test Area</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="testArea1"></label></td>  
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Technology Long Form</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="testCategory1"></label></td>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Technology Short Form</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="testCategory2"></label></td>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Sub Test Technology</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="subTestCategory1"></label></td> 
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">TAT</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="tat1"></label></td>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Test MRP</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="testMrp1"></label></td>
                                            <td class="col-md-2">Specimen Type</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2" id="specimenType1">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>

                                              <td class="col-md-2">Preservation</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="preservation1"></label></td>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Comment</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="comment1"></label></td> 
                                                    <td class="col-md-2">NABL Accredited</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="nablAccredited"></label></td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                           <td class="col-md-2">Test Type</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="testType1"></label></td>

                                                    <td class="col-md-2">Site</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="site1"></label></td> 
                                                      <td class="col-md-2">Department</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="department1"></label></td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>

                                                     <td class="col-md-2">Sub Department</td>
                                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="subdepartment1"></label></td>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">Description</td>
                                              <td class="col-md-2">
                                                    <label id="description1"></label></td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [z-Index](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_zindex.asp) to solve your problem. For example:

```
var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
$(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
}, 0);
```

Here is [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CxdUQ/)